# Plugins for users to use on websites-PHP

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter to make a website.

I want to provide users with Plugin/Iframe/banner etc so that they can use it simply by copy pasting code.

I dont want to make image banners because of limitations and dynamic data.

Like the facebook one below .
It is clickable with different links unlike Image banners.

The data in the Box will change every time page is refreshed(almost realtime).

the box should be dynamic i.e different for  user with ID1 ,ID2.

Using iframe is an option with something like example.php?banner=ID1

But i dont want user to edit links /text in that.

How should i proceed ?

[image: Fb social Plugin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple.

[ 1 ] Start building your dynamic application. You can provide unique URL to each user based on USERID or USERNAME like

[http://www.stackovrflow.com/users/content/{user_id} OR {username}](http://www.stackovrflow.com/users/content/%7Buser_id%7D%20OR%20%7Busername%7D)

[ 2 ] Create JavaScript API / Restful API. When Visitor clicks on the link control the click with JS. I mean open new window like Facebook or redirect to your website. The page load above dynamic URL. See the details about New Window.

[How can I open a link in a new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827637/jquery-open-link-in-new-window)

[ 3 ] This is quite possible using IFrame also providing few lines of code. But it is not preferred. Using / Providing API is always best.

Comment: Thanks. I am stuck at step 2 (dont know how to create APIs).Any pre existing Library or Link ?

Comment: It's not hard to build API's if you are good at JS or any other server side languages. :) Look into this also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680397/creating-javascript-api-like-facebook-and-twitter